# Program with mkfifo() and open() cannot exit

Tags: c, fifo

I am trying to use FIFO for interprocessing. But when trying to create a FIFO and then open it, my program hangs (cannot exit).

```
if (mkfifo("./fifo.txt", S_IRUSR | S_IWUSE) < 0) {
    fprint("Can not create fifo");
    return 1;
}
if ((readfd = open("./fifo.txt", O_RDONLY)) < 0) {
    return 1;
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Use [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) on your program. And call [perror(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html) on error.

Comment: "Opening a FIFO for reading normally blocks until some other process opens the same FIFO for writing, and vice versa." https://linux.die.net/man/3/mkfifo

Answer (score 3):

Read [fifo(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fifo.7.html), notably:

> Normally, opening the FIFO blocks until the other end is opened also.

So I guess that your call to [open(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) is blocked.  Perhaps you want to pass the `O_NONBLOCK` flag.

You should use [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) to debug your program (and perhaps also `strace` the *other* program on the other end of the fifo). And call [perror(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html) on error.

Perhaps using [unix(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html) sockets could be more relevant in your case. You can then [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) before [accept(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/accept.2.html)

You should read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/).

Comment: Thank you Basile, after creating a FIFO and writing somthing to it. Then I tried to read this FIFO from another process and it works (I mean, it can exit)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

void child(void)
{
    int fd = 0;
    if ((fd = open("./fifo.txt", O_WRONLY)) < 0) {
        return;
    }

    write(fd, "hello world!", 12);
}

void parent(void)
{
    int fd = 0;
    if ((fd = open("./fifo.txt", O_RDONLY)) < 0) {
        return;
    }

    char buf[36] = {0};
    read(fd, buf, 36);
    printf("%s\n", buf);
}


int main(void)
{
    pid_t pid = 0;

    if (mkfifo("./fifo.txt", S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR) < 0) {
        printf("Can not create fifo\n");
        return 1;
    }

    pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0) {
        printf("child process\n");
        child();
    } else if (pid < 0) {
        printf("fork error\n");
        return -1;
    }

    parent();
}
```